# Not Able to hit Node/Express Backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have created a backend service using Node and Express. I am not able to hit any route for this application. If routes are misconfigured then I should get an error on console, but I am not getting an error as well.

**index.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const server = http.createServer(app);

const {API_PORT} = process.env;
const port = process.env.PORT || API_PORT;


server.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`Server Running on port ${port}`);
})
```

**app.js**

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const loginRoute = require("./routes/login");
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/unsecure',loginRoute);

module.exports = app;
```

**login.js** (Route)

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const loginController = require("../controller/login.controller");


router.post('/login',loginController.loginUser);
router.post('/register',loginController.registerUser);

module.exports = router;
```

**.env**

```
API_PORT=4001
DB_HOST= hostname
DB_PASSWORD= password
DB_PORT=5432
DB_USERNAME= username
```

Comment: Does your loginController load correctly? This line looks wrong require("../controller/login.controller")

Comment: Hey.. it was throwing an error in controller. I found it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

reminder that when you added '/unsecure' you also need to use it during post request

```
app.use('/unsecure',loginRoute);
//request from client:
'/unsecure/login' // must be of type POST
'/unsecure/register' // must be of type POST
```

Comment: localhost:4001/unsecure/register . I am making a post request to it. Still not working.

Answer (score 1):

I was exploring your code, you have not given the controller code, but still i found no error, all url were working. I think you might be hitting wrong url

your url should be -

```
{root}/unsecure/login
{root}/unsecure/register
```

According to .env you have given it should be -

```
http://localhost:4001/unsecure/login    
http://localhost:4001/unsecure/register
```

Comment: http://localhost:4001/unsecure/register . I am making a post request to it. Still not working

Comment: can you share your controller code?

Comment: Hey.. it was throwing an error in controller. I found it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good to hear that!